# Screen Orientation in Android Application

Tags: android, orientation

I used the `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` and `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` for screen orientation in my android app and it is working Correctly.
I knew that `setRequestedOrientation` require an int parameter as an argument. So I Tried to Find out Value of `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` and `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` . And Atlast i found these value is 0 for landscape mode and 1 for portrait mode.
Even `setRequestedOrientation(1)` and `setRequestedOrientation(0)` works well in my application.
Now My Question is It is Good Practice to use 0 and 1 Instead of `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` and `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same.

```
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

and

```
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

are STATIC variables. So they will not effect your app performance while runtime.

But as Vyacheslav mentioned, it is better to use variables for readability.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem to use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`? It might be in future not useful. Constanst are more readable and useful while refactoring. The other people can easily understand if you use words instead of digits.

Comment: According to you, Both work same. But sake of Readability Purpose i should use Constants. But i can use digits(0 or 1) for my & only my  personal implementations.

Comment: Yes of course you can. But if you read your code after several years you can forget it;)